# If a cyclic group has an element of infinite order, how many elements of finite order does it have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

If a cyclic group has an element of infinite order, how many elements of finite order does it have?

I know that the order of the entire group must be infinite, for an element of the group must have an order less than the group order. My first thought was that there are no elements with finite order in this group, however now I'm believing that there are infinitely many elements of finite order, since the group should have infinitely many elements. Can someone explain the solution?

Comment: So you are saying $G = (a)$, where $a$ has infinite order. Then an element in $G$ has the form $a^n$, and what is its order?

Comment: This is exercise 18 in chapter 4 of Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first thought was almost right: the only element of finite order is the identity. If $G$ is an infinite cyclic group, then $G=\{g^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ for some $g\in G$. If $x\in G$, then $x=g^m$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z^+$. If $m\ne 0$, so that $x$ is not the identity element, then for each $k\in\Bbb Z$ we have $x^k=(g^m)^k=g^{km}$, and $g^{km}=g^0$ if and only if $km=0$ and hence if and only if $k=0$. In other words, no positive power of $x$ is the identity, and therefore $x$ has infinite order.

Comment: The identity having finite order makes plenty of sense, but in words can you explain why every other element in this cyclic group has an infinite order?

Comment: @PythagorasWannaBe: The group is cyclic, so it has a generator $g$ such that every element of the group is a power of $g$. If $x$ is an element of finite order, say order $m$, then $x^m=e$ (where $e$ is the identity of the group. But $x$ is a power of $g$, so $x^m$ is also a power of $g$, so some power of $g$ is the identity. But then $g$ has finite order, and the group must be finite.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G = <g>$ be a cyclic group of infinite order, where $g \in G$ is a generator. What can you say about the order of the element $g^k \in G$? Consider the cases $k=0$ and $k \neq 0$.